# Not receiving push notifications for deleted events?

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

I have a calendar tool that integrates with Outlook Calendar.  To respond to changes on the Outlook side, I subscribe to push notifications. If I miss the first notification of a change, Outlook sends others with `ChangeType: 'Missed'` and I synchronize with the user's calendar to retrieve the details of the change.  However, deleted events do not seem to be included in the sync response.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#sync-events) suggests that it is possible to get deleted events:

> Synchronize and get new, updated, or deleted events in a specified time range from the user's primary calendar (`../me/calendarview`) or from a different calendar.

There is even a [section about deleted events and synchronization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/sync-calendar-view#deleted-events-and-synchronization).

> Deleted events will contain a reason property with the value of "deleted" to indicate a deleted entity. If the event is a recurring master event, you should delete all of the occurrences and exceptions.

`'Created'` and `'Updated'` `ChangeTypes` work fine.

Am I subscribing incorrectly?  Or is this not a feature of the Outlook Calendar API?

Here is the body of my subscription request:

```json
{
   '@odata.type': '#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription',
   'Resource': "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars/#{calendar_id}/events",
   'NotificationURL': MY_URL,
   'ChangeType': 'Created, Updated, Deleted',
   'ClientState': 'foo',
   'SubscriptionExpirationDateTime': TTL.minutes.from_now.iso8601
}
```